# True or False: A homogeneous system of linear equations must have a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra

a linear system whose equations are all homogeneous must have a unique solution

This is a true or false exercise, and I think this is false.

My counterexample is $~x+y=0$, $~2x+2y=0~$ this is also homogeneous linear equation whose solution is not unique.

But in textbook, the answer of problem is 'true'.

Comment: Even simpler: if you work over an infinite field, then the homogeneous system $\;x+y=0\;$ has more than one solution. In fact, infinitely many.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "true"? Surely it must be wrong then. If by "unique solution", you mean that it cannot have infinitely many, and since homogenous systems must have at least one (the trivial) solution, then it is easy to bring up a counterexample (as you have) of a homogenous system with non-unique (infinitely many) solutions.

Furthermore is that any system in $A$, such that $dim(kerA) > 0$ will have infinitely many non-unique solutions (provided under the implicit assumption that the underlying field is infinite).

Comment: Yes now I solved more exercises, and there exists some wrong answers like this. Furthernore  In another chapter, problem is (a) to (k), but answer is (a) to (m).  I think this textbook is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Excluding the somewhat silly case where there are no unknowns at all, the empty set of equations does not have a unique solution. Any assignment of values to the unknowns vacuously satisfies an empty set of equations, so there is no unique solution. And of course (vacuously), all equations in an empty set are both linear and homogeneous.